# Is there a DirectShow filter that sends incoming stream to remote server over HTTP?

Tags: windows, directshow

I see that there is the File Writer filter available in DirectShow, which can either write a stream (data of major type `MEDIATYPE_Stream`) to a [local] file or publish it on a URL. You'd think the latter is what I want, but from what I understand, it creates a HTTP endpoint exposing the stream on the specified URL. For remote clients that will connect and consume this stream. Basically, a streaming server. Which is *not* what I want.

What I am looking for is a filter that connects to a *remote* HTTP server and uploads the data it receives upstream over HTTP using say, POST or PUT method.

Is there something like this available?

I'd imagine this filter, just like the File Writer filter, take a `MEDIATYPE_Stream` on its input pin, and just like File Writer, be a "renderer" filter -- not having any output pins.

I am not an expert with DirectShow, but I have some experience with it and have played around with Graph Studio Next just to see what connects where and how. Anyhow, please feel free to point out any glaring conceptual errors I am displaying here. I sure hope this is not a case of an XY problem.

Comment: This should be easy to implement, but what would you send?
Raw data or encoded video/audio can be send sequential. If you have a mixer (v+a => mts/mp4/avi = MEDIATYPE_Stream) the data will (except for MTS/Mpeg) not be sequential! Most mixers write an header after the stream stop, for the beginning of the "File". So you need to also send the file position for each data package.

Comment: Thanks, let me clarify. My input is always invariably going to be a muxed stream. I think that's what you call "mixed" data. An MP4 contianer, for instance. Are you saying that the file writer filter does random access on the output file? If the upstream data is sequential, then my filter will work in FIFO mode, no? Data comes in at the input pin and is POSTed/PUT via HTTP. I can't see why the data output by a muxer filter would NOT be sequential? But that's where my knowledge is a bit blurry to say the least.

Comment: All "muxer"-filters I know are writing after the stop signal at the start of the file. (Except MTS, because MTS is a streaming file format). You can test your muxer with the "AnalyzerWriterFiler" of GrapStudioNext.

Comment: What's a stop signal? Anyway, I figure that if FileWriter can *save* a coherent, functioning container, I can send a container over the wire. If I have to do some accumulation and assembly in the filter, reordering data so that it can be FIFOed out of it, then I'll just have to do that. I will look at the filter you mention, of course.

Comment: The container is created by the muxer-filter. The filewriter is just the endpoint where the data is written on the harddisk. The filewriter implements the IStream interface, so a muxer filter can write header-data for the container after the filtergraph has been stopped. With the AnalyzerWriterFilter in GraphStudioNext you can see when and where the data is written.

Comment: By the way, Webm containers don't need patching headers after they're sent. I've verified this.